# How can I render the data of my current Slide of the Slick Slider with click of the button to another page using React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAMT9.png)

I am trying to render the data from the current slide of the Slick slider to a component to another page with react router.

I have a Card component for every card and CardList component for the upper cards like in the screenshot and also component for the SlickSlider. They are all in the section component which also contains the button.

For the SlickSlider comp. and the CardList comp. i used Forwarding Ref so when i click on one of the upper cards to change the same card in the Slick Slider.

Now i want when i click on the button under the slider to transfer and render the data of the current slide to another page using React Router but don't have really an idea. I thought of useParams() but im using json.data doc for the data of the cards.

```
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css"; 
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
import Card from "../Card/Card";
import "./SlickSlider.css"
import { forwardRef } from "react";

const SlickSlider = forwardRef (({data},ref) => {

  const settings = {
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true,
  };
  

  return (
    <>
    <div className="slick-slider">
      <Slider ref={ref} {...settings}>
        {data.map((card) => (
          <Card src={card.src} title={card.title} key={card.id} id={card.id} location={card.city} />
        ))}
      </Slider> 
    </div>
    </>
  )
})

export default SlickSlider
```

```
import React from 'react'
import "./CardList.css"
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Card from '../Card/Card';


const CardList = ({handleClick}) => {
  const [cardData, setCardData] = useState([]);
  const API_URL = "data.json";

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
  //     .then((res) => res.json())
  //     .then((data) => console.log(data.slice(0, 5)))
  //     .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
  // }, []); 

  const getData = async () => {
    const objRequest = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    };

    try {
      const response = await fetch(API_URL, objRequest);
      if (!response.ok) throw Error("ERROR");
      const data = await response.json();
      setCardData(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

 
  return (
    <div className='card-list-container'>
      {cardData.length > 0 && cardData.map((card, index) => (
        <Card handleClick={() => handleClick(index)} index={index} key={card.id} title={card.title} src={card.src}/>
      ))}
      {cardData.length === 0 && <h3>Loading...</h3>}
    </div>
  )
}

export default CardList
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRef } from "react";
import Button from "../button/Button";
import CardList from "../CardList/CardList";
import SlickSlider from "../slick-slider/SlickSlider";
import "./NewSliderSection.css";

const NewSliderSection = () => {
  const API_URL = "data.json";
  const [cardData, setCardData] = useState([]);
  const slideRef = useRef(null);

  const getData = async () => {
    const objRequest = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    };

    try {
      const response = await fetch(API_URL, objRequest);
      if (!response.ok) throw Error("ERROR");
      const data = await response.json();
      setCardData(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const handleClick = (index) => {
    slideRef.current?.slickGoTo(index);
  };


  console.log(slideRef);

  return (
    <div className="new-slider-section">
      <CardList handleClick={handleClick} />
      <SlickSlider data={cardData} ref={slideRef} />
      {/* <button className="button" onClick={routeChange}>
        See more...
      </button> */}
      <Button />
    </div>
  );
};

export default NewSliderSection;
```

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import "./Button.css"

const Button = () => {
  return (
    <Link className='link' target="_blank" to={`/details`}>
      <button className='button'>See more...</button>
    </Link>
  ) 
}

export default Button
```

```
import React from 'react'
import "./CardDetails.css"

const CardDetails = () => {
  return (
    <div className='card-details'>CardDetails

    </div>
  )
}

export default CardDetails
```

```
import { Route, Router, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Button from './components/button/Button';
import CardDetails from './components/card-details/CardDetails';
import Footer from './components/footer/Footer';
import Hero from './components/hero/Hero';
import Navbar from './components/navbar/Navbar';
import NewSliderSection from './components/new-slider-section/NewSliderSection';
import SectionOne from './components/section-1/SectionOne';
import SectionThree from './components/section-3/SectionThree';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import UserDetails from './pages/UserDetails';
// import SlideSection from './components/slide-section/SlideSection';



function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />}/>
        <Route path='/details' element={<UserDetails/>}/>
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
   
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from 'react'
import CardDetails from '../components/card-details/CardDetails'

const UserDetails = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <CardDetails />
    </div>
  )
}

export default UserDetails
```

Comment: What is the "other" page you want to render some content on? Please share all relevant code you are working with and have an issue using? This includes the app's routing/navigation components. See [mcve].

Comment: I edited the code. I want to show the current slide data in the CardDetails component which is in the UserDetails page. Now I am using the Button component as a link to open the UserDetails page

Comment: So basically you want to click the "See More" button and pass the data of the current active slide to the `"/details"` path, to `UserDetails`?

Comment: Yes, I want to achieve exactly that.

Comment: From the `SlickSlider` component is there a way to access or know what the active slide is? `NewSliderSection` appears to hold the `cardData` and a ref, can these be used to derive the active slide's data?

Comment: From the Slick docs https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/api  now i see there is a property initialSlide and the default is 0. Previously i used the slickGoTo() method so when you click on one of the cards above the slider to change the slide that is matching the index.

Comment: Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that we could work from? I have an idea but it would be easier to start from your code instead of guessing if this is all of it.

Comment: Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/zh1f2j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Slider` component from `react-slick` offers a `beforeChange` callback prop that passed the previous and next slide indices. You can use the next index to derive the correct card data to forward to the `"/details"` route via `Link` component state.

Example:

SlickSlider

Consume an additional `onChange` prop passed to the `Slider` component's `beforeChange` prop.

```
const SlickSlider = forwardRef(({ data, onSlideChange }, ref) => {
  const settings = {
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true,
    beforeChange: onSlideChange
  };

  ...
});
```

Button

Consume a `data` prop and pass in `Link` state.

```
const Button = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <Link className="link" to="/details" state={{ data }}>
      <button className="button">See more...</button>
    </Link>
  );
};
```

NewSliderSection

Add a new `slideindex` state that is updated via an `onChange` callback passed to `SlickSlider`, and derives the active card data to be passed to `Button`.

```
const NewSliderSection = () => {
  ...
  const [cardData, setCardData] = useState([]);
  const slideRef = useRef(null);
  const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(0);

  ...

  return (
    <div className="new-slider-section">
      ...
      <SlickSlider
        data={cardData}
        onSlideChange={(_, slideIndex) => setSlideIndex(slideIndex)}
        ref={slideRef}
      />
      <Button data={cardData[slideIndex]} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

CardDetails

Access the passed `Link` state via the `useLocation` hook and use it accordingly.

```
const CardDetails = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const { data } = state || {};

  if (!data) {
    return "No data.";
  }

  return (
    <div className="card-details">
      CardDetails
      <p>ID: {data.id}</p>
      <p>Title: {data.title}</p>
      <p>City: {data.city}</p>
      <img src={data.src} alt="" height={200} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit how-can-i-render-the-data-of-my-current-slide-of-the-slick-slider-with-click-of]

Comment: Very helpful Drew, especially the usage of useLocation() hook ! Ty